# Nginx block GET requests on specific port

Tags: nginx

Im looking for a way to block GET requests on a specific port, something like this probably:

```
location <:PORT_NUMBER> {
    limit_except GET {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this, I want to block all GET request to `:5432`